# How QGIS shows "EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 - Geographic" for the GeoTIFF file's CRS, and how to reproduce it in GDAL and Python?

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system, gdal

I have a GeoTIFF file (named avhrr.tif), and tried detect it's CRS in `Python` and `gdal` and compare it's values with that in `QGIS`. Here is a screenshot that is taken from the QGIS:
[image]

Here is the code that I used in Python:

```
from osgeo import gdal, osr

dataset = gdal.Open("avhrr.tif", gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
prj=dataset.GetProjection()

srs=osr.SpatialReference(wkt=prj)
print(srs)
```

which prints:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AXIS["Latitude",NORTH],
    AXIS["Longitude",EAST],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

1. It seems that `QGIS` is showing `GEOGCS`'s `AUTHORITY` which is `["EPSG","4326"]` as CRS in the picture. Why is it so?
2. Why there is a 'Geographic' at the end of the CRS text that QGIS produces, and what does it say? How can I reproduce it in `gdal`?

Comment: Did you look at the QGIS code to see how they did it?

Comment: GEOGCS stands for "Geographic coordinate system". Authority code for this GEOGCS means EPSG:4326 (epsg.io/4326). QGIS tries to show the most interesting parts of the WKT in a user friendly way. About WKT see for example http://www.geoapi.org/3.0/javadoc/org/opengis/referencing/doc-files/WKT.html.

Comment: @IanTurton No I didn't. I should definitely look at their code. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you for the valuable link. I'm reading it.